# how to iterate two int array in arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to iterate int array in array-list I had browsed in all those contain single array in array-list iterate but now am trying to iterate two int array in array list how to achieve this in single arraylist??

```
static void arraylist()
{
    int []a={1,4,6,7};
    int []b={2,3,5};

    ArrayList<int[]> aa=new ArrayList<int[]>();
    aa.add(a);
    aa.add(b);

    int[] contentFromList = aa.get(0) ;
    for (int i = 0; i < contentFromList.length; i++) {
        int j = contentFromList[i];
        System.out.println("Value at index - "+i+" is :"+j);
    }
}
```

output:

```
Value at index - 0 is :1
Value at index - 1 is :4
Value at index - 2 is :6
Value at index - 3 is :7
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another loop like below,

Please format the below code.

```
static void arraylist() {
        int []a={1,4,6,7};
        int []b={2,3,5};

        ArrayList<int[]> aa=new ArrayList<int[]>();
        aa.add(a);
        aa.add(b);

        for(int k = 0; k < aa.size(); k++) {
           int[] contentFromList = aa.get(k) ;
           for (int i = 0; i < contentFromList.length; i++) {
              int j = contentFromList[i];
              System.out.println("Value at index - "+ i +" is :" + j);
           }
        }
}
```

As per my understanding of your comment, maybe you need below code.

```
static void arraylist() {
        int []a={1,4,6,7};
        int []b={2,3,5};

        ArrayList<int[]> aa=new ArrayList<int[]>();
        aa.add(Arrays.asList(a));
        aa.add(Arrays.asList(b));

        int[] contentFromList = aa.get(k) ;
        for (int i = 0; i < contentFromList.length; i++) {
           int j = contentFromList[i];
           System.out.println("Value at index - "+ i +" is :" + j);
        }
}
```

`Arrays.asList(a)` will convert your array "a" to a `List` which will then be added to your `ArrayList` **aa**. After that, all the elements will become part of a single list.

Comment: it show error on this line for(int k = 0; k < aa.size(); aa++) Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<int[]> to int

Comment: change it to `int k = 0; k < aa.size(); k++`

Comment: i printed a index it show like separately is possible to add in same array like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Value at index - 0 is :1
Value at index - 1 is :4
Value at index - 2 is :6
Value at index - 3 is :7
Value at index - 0 is :2
Value at index - 1 is :3
Value at index - 2 is :5

Answer (score 0):

Another loop required for arraylist. Below is the code

```
static void arraylist()
    {
        int []a={1,4,6,7};
        int []b={2,3,5};

        ArrayList<int[]> aa=new ArrayList<int[]>();
        aa.add(a);
        aa.add(b);

        for(int z=0; z < aa.size(); z++){
            int[] contentFromList = aa.get(z);

            for (int i = 0; i < contentFromList.length; i++) {
                int j = contentFromList[i];
                System.out.println("Value at index - "+i+" is :"+j);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1 more loop to read data from second array also :

```
static void arraylist()
{
    int []a={1,4,6,7};
    int []b={2,3,5};

    ArrayList<int[]> aa=new ArrayList<int[]>();
    aa.add(a);
    aa.add(b);

for(int k = 0; k < aa.size(); k++) {
int[] contentFromList = aa.get(k) ;
for (int i = 0; i < contentFromList.length; i++) {
    int j = contentFromList[i];
    System.out.println("Value at index - "+i+" is :"+j);
            }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a reason to mix `Collection`(s) and an array. So, I would start with a

```
List<List<Integer>> aa = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you could add `Integer[]` values like

```
Integer[] a = { 1, 4, 6, 7 };
Integer[] b = { 2, 3, 5 };
List<List<Integer>> aa = new ArrayList<>();
aa.add(Arrays.asList(a));
aa.add(Arrays.asList(b));
System.out.println(aa);
```

and get

```
[[1, 4, 6, 7], [2, 3, 5]]
```

Conversely, if you must use a `List<int[]>`, then something like

```
int[] a = { 1, 4, 6, 7 };
int[] b = { 2, 3, 5 };
List<int[]> aa = new ArrayList<>();
aa.add(a);
aa.add(b);
System.out.print("[");
for (int i = 0; i < aa.size(); i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(aa.get(i)));
}
System.out.println("]");
```

is necessary to produce the previous output. Java arrays do not override `Object.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Java8 Stream solution.

It's easy and efficient, you get benefit of **lazy evaluation**:

```
aa.stream().flatMap(arr -> {

        Stream.Builder<Integer> build = Stream.builder();
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            build.add(arr[i]);
        return build.build();

}).forEach(System.out::println);
```